# Good resources for learning database optimization part

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am good at database(sql) programming part but I want to move ahead into database optimization part like: where and when to indexes, how to decide which query is better than other, how to optimize database. Can you guide me some good resources or books which can lead me to this?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?  A lot of this will be specific to the RDBMS since the query analyzers/optimizers are different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Inside Microsoft SQL Server 2005: Query Tuning and Optimization](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735621969),

[Inside Microsoft SQL Server 2005: T-SQL Querying](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735623139)

[Inside Microsoft SQL Server 2005: The Storage Engine](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735621055)

have very deep and thorough explanation of optimizing sql server querying.

Answer (score 4):

[SQL Server Query Performance Tuning Distilled, Second Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590594215)

Answer (score 0):

I've recently been focusing on this for my company, and I've learned some interesting things about specifically query optimization.

I've run SQL Profiler for a half hour at a time and logged queries that required 1000 reads or more (then later ones that required 50 CPU or more).

I originally focused on individual queries with the highest reads and CPU.  However, having written the logs to a database, I was able to query aggregate results to see which queries required the most aggregate reads and CPU.  Targeting these actually helped a lot more than only targeting the most expensive queries.

The most expensive query might be run once a day, so it's good to optimize that.  However, if the 10th most expensive query is run 100 times an hour, it's much more helpful to optimize that first.

Here's a summary of what I've learned so far, which can help you get started in identifying queries for optimization:

[A Beginner's Guide to Database Query Optimization](http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/sql-server-database-optimization-a-beginners-guide/)

[Highly Inefficient Linq Queries that Break Database Indexing](http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/highly-inefficient-linq-queries-that-break-database-indexing/)

[An Obscure Performance Pitfall for Test Accounts and Improperly Indexed Database Tables](http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/an-obscure-performance-pitfall-for-test-accounts-and-improperly-indexed-database-tables/)

Answer (score 0):

**Please find some tips for database/query optimization.**

**Apply functions to parameters, not columns**

One of the most common mistakes seen when looking at database queries, is the improper use of functions against database tables. Whenever we need to apply a function to a column and validate the result against a value, it's worth checking if we have the reverse function that we can apply against the given column. In this way, the database engine can use an index against that column, and there isn't the need to define a functional based index.

against a 60 rows table with no indexes whatsoever, the following query

```
SELECT ticker.SYMBOL,
ticker.TSTAMP,
ticker.PRICE
FROM ticker
WHERE TO_CHAR(ticker.TSTAMP, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = '2011-04-01'
```

executes in 0.006s, whereas, the "reverse" query

```
SELECT ticker.SYMBOL,
ticker.TSTAMP,
ticker.PRICE
FROM ticker
WHERE
ticker.TSTAMP = TO_DATE('2011-04-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

-- executes in 0.004s

**Exists clause instead of IN (subquery)**

Another observed pattern in database development is that people choose the easy and the most convenient solution and for this tip, we will take a look at finding an element in a list. The easiest and most convenient solution is using the IN operator.

```
SELECT symbol, tstamp, price
FROM ticker
WHERE price IN (3,4,5);
```

--or
    SELECT symbol, tstamp, price
    FROM ticker
    WHERE price IN (SELECT price FROM threshold WHERE action = 'Buy');

This approach is ok when we have a small manageable list. When the list becomes extensively large and when the list is dynamic(it will be generated based on parameters that we'll have only at runtime) this approach tends to becomes quite costly for the database. The alternative solution is the use of the EXISTS operator as shown in the below code snippet:

```
SELECT symbol, tstamp, price
FROM ticker t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM threshold m WHERE t.price = m.price AND m.action = 'Buy');
```

This approach will be faster because once the engine has found a hit, it will quit looking as the condition has proved true. With IN it will collect all the results from the subquery before further processing.